# Logging ISDN events with dahdi and freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch, isdn

I am using `freeswitch` with `dahdi`. I have a need to log the ISDN events for all the calls that land on the PBX (`freeswitch`).  Is there any way to do this?. I thank you kindly for your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change to your dahdi source directory and issue:

```
apt-get install libpcap-dev || yum install libpcap-devel
sed 's/^.*\(\#define\s\+CONFIG_DAHDI_MIRROR\).*$/\1/' linux/include/dahdi/dahdi_config.h
make clean
make all
make install
cd tools
make dahdi_pcap
```

If compiled without errors you now have a tool called dahdi_pcap and you can capture the signaling to a pcap file and analyze it using wireshark. usage example:

```
./dahdi_pcap -p lapd -c 1 -f isdn.pcap
```